# How to get buyer info and transaction id from paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I would like to get buyer first name, buyer last name (that is in the account of the user), as well as buyer transaction ID, during IPN postback to save in database. How could it be done? I can't seems to find any variable associated with it.

Is the first name and last name is getting from Buyer Information Variables?

Comment: Are you not getting this data in the post variables??

Comment: it works all of the sudden